# ошибка кода с возведением чисел в квадрат

Tags: python

Код простой. По моей логике должен быть результат `[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]`.

Сам код:

```
for a in range(1,11):
    b=a**2
    v.append(b)
    print(v)
```

помогите найти ошибку

Comment: Вы на каждой итерации хотите печатать удлиняющийся список? Если нет, то уберите сдвиг перед print

Comment: нужно список инициализировать, перед циклом `v=[]` и print влево подвинуть

Comment: Какое сообщение об ошибке вы получаете для данного кода?

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без **явного описания проблемы** бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

```
+ v = []
```

```
-     print(v)
+ print(v)
```

.

Comment: не факт, что автор вопроса поймёт ваш ответ...

Comment: @Danis, ну пусть постарается)